# Grid is not loading showing just the spinner without errors in logs or console

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4.1, listing-component

I'm trying to follow the guide `https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-admin-grid/` to add a custom admin grid however I'm stuck in a situation where there's no error and the spinner keeps loading forever without loading the grid.

[image]

Log files system.log, debug.log, exception.log are empty

Javascript console only shows this clean of errors screen

[image]

Finally I can see from mui/index/render XHR request that data is fetched and in proper format

[image]

Here's my files

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
file: app/code/Ioweb/GiftCards/etc/di.xml
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


    <virtualType name="IowebGiftCardCollection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">salesrule_coupon_giftcard_order</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\ResourceModel\GiftCardSummary</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">IowebGiftCardCollection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

My listing component

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 * file: app/code/Ioweb/GiftCards/view/adminhtml/ui_component/giftcardsummary_listing.xml
-->

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">ioweb_gift_cards_listing.ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">ioweb_gift_cards_listing.ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">gift_cards_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>gift_cards_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>ioweb_gift_cards_listing.ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Ioweb_GiftCards::management</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Ioweb\GiftCards\Ui\DataProvider\GiftCardsDataProvider" name="ioweb_gift_cards_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <!--        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>-->
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="gift_cards_columns">
        <column name="id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

My DataProvider

```php
<?php
namespace Ioweb\GiftCards\Ui\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider;

class GiftCardsDataProvider extends DataProvider
{
}
```

The model

```
<?php

namespace Ioweb\GiftCards\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class GiftCardSummary extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\ResourceModel\GiftCardSummary::class);
    }
}
```

The ResourceModel

```php
<?php

namespace Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\ResourceModel;

class GiftCardSummary extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Main table name
     */
    const MAIN_TABLE_NAME = 'salesrule_coupon_giftcard_order';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(self::MAIN_TABLE_NAME, 'id');
    }
}
```

The collection

```php
<?php
namespace Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\ResourceModel\GiftCardSummary;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\GiftCardSummary::class,
            \Ioweb\GiftCards\Model\ResourceModel\GiftCardSummary::class
        );
    }
}
```

I don't see something obviously wrong with the declarations, any ideas why it doesn't render the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Please Add below Code to listing file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 * file: app/code/Ioweb/GiftCards/view/adminhtml/ui_component/giftcardsummary_listing.xml
-->

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">giftcardsummary_listing.giftcardsummary_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">giftcardsummary_listing.giftcardsummary_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>gift_cards_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>giftcardsummary_listing.giftcardsummary_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="giftcardsummary_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Ioweb_GiftCards::management</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Ioweb\GiftCards\Ui\DataProvider\GiftCardsDataProvider" name="giftcardsummary_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <!--        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>-->
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="gift_cards_columns">
        <column name="id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Let me know if any Query..**